# Trouble in understanding center conditions in the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 p(x) + y^3 q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Start defining the ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = p(x)y^2 + q(x)y^3, \hspace{0.2cm} a \leq x \leq b  \quad (1)  $$

where $p$, $q$ are polynomials and $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\phi(t,c)$ be the solution of the the Cauchy problem

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = p(x)y^2 + q(x)y^3, \quad y(a) = c, $$
where $c$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$.

We say that there is a center in (1) between $a$ and $b$, if for all  small $c$ close to $0$ , is satisfied $\phi(a,c) = \phi(b,c) \equiv c$.

The book that I'm studying the center-focus problem, says that "We can supose without loss of generality $a=0$ and $b=1$, so a study of the return map calculations described above shows that this condition is equivalent to 
$$P(1) = P(0), \quad \int_{0}^{1}P(x)^n q(x) dx =0, \hspace{0.1cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$
where $P(x) = \int_{0}^{x} p(\xi) d \xi$ (in this case $0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$)"

But the book doesn't prove this statement and I really want to know why this is true.  Can someone  help me?

Comment: What book are you using/citing/quoting?

Comment: Lymit Cycles of Differential Equations, Colin Chistopher and Chengzhi Li. Page 53